# Why is my network route performing oddly

Tags: arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, route

I'm running Arcmap 10.2.2 and am messing with network analyst for the first time.  I used QGIS to download an OSM layer that I imported into an enterprise geodatabase.  I created a network with all the roads and set connectivity to Any vertex.  I selected two points which can be seen in the attached image.  I ran a route with just these two points and it goes way out of the way.  The distance should about 20 miles and it comes out as 118 miles.

Any thoughts how I can correct this issue?

[image]

Comment: You may have breaks in the Network.  A visual inspection may find small gaps between line segments. If this is due to the original dataset or as a result of the translation is a mute point.

Comment: What license level do you have (Basic, Standard, Advanced)? The first thing I would do is run a topology check on the lines you created the network from. There are several possible checks, but the quickest and most telling is probably dangles - if you see a bunch of errors that aren't at dead-end streets, you've got a lot of cleanup work to do. A visual check may find these, or it may not depending on how close the points are when not snapped, which is why I suggest topology. The problem may also be your edge attributes, evaluator config, or impedence settings (or other restriction settings).

Answer (score 0):

Common problems I have had include break in the network, as mentioned before. You can fix this with the Integrate GP tool - but read up on the tool because you have to set the tolerance right. You also have to make sure that you have nodes at all road intersections. The "Planarize Lines" tool under "Advanced editing" will split all your roads at their intersections and create nodes there so that your "route" can find the right places to turn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to improve your answer provide additional resources to the various tools and how to use them (ArcGIS help).